# Send raw Ethernet frame with custom data after EtherType using nping

Tags: packet, nmap, packet-injection

I am using nping to send raw a Ethernet frame.  I want to send a frame with custom data starting after the EtherType.  However, nping puts the custom data in the middle of the packet.  For example, here's my command:

```
nping --dest-mac <my mac> --ether-type 0xd2d2  -e eth0 --send-eth --data 00010028 192.168.2.10
```

and here's what I see on the receiver:

```
    0x0000:  8cfd f000 cb16 9410 3eb8 483d d2d2 4500
    0x0010:  0020 f412 0000 4001 0169 c0a8 0207 c0a8
    0x0020:  020a 0800 9a72 5d61 0003 0001 0028 0000
    0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

In the third line I want the 6th and 7th half words, `0001 0028` to come after `0xd2d2`

Answer (score 0):

The custom data nping put is an IP header.

I'm not familiar with nping, but I guess the `192.168.2.10` you put at the end of your command is doing wrong. It's encoded at 16th and 17th half words (destination IP address) as `c0a8 020a`. Probably nping added the IP header because you specified `192.168.2.10`.

Try the command without `192.168.2.10`, or `<my mac>` instead of `192.168.2.10`.

Comment: I have to specify the IP address, otherwise nping throws an error.  This even though I am specifying the interface directly (```-e eth0```) and specifying that I want to send a raw Ethernet frame (```--send-eth```).

Comment: Putting <my mac> instead of 192.168.2.10 doesn't work? I guess not, though, as far as I read [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nping).

Comment: Do you need to use nping? I can write java code to work for you using pcap4j if you want.

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up using Ostinato to generate the packet.  I just wanted some tool to generate raw packets on Windows.